# How to compare typescript type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How can I compare typescript types in this scenario

```
interface TableParams extends TableProps {
  data: Array<object> | JSX.Element
}

export const BasicTable = ({ data}: TableParams) => {
  if(typeof data == Array<object>){ // typeof data = object
    //do something
  }
  
  if(typeof data == JSX.Element){ //typeof data = object
    //do something 
  }
}
```

So I can pass an array of objects or a JSX element. If an array passed through the props I'd like to do something if a JSX element passed I'd like to simply return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.isArray` and (probably) `instanceof`

```
if(Array.isArray(data)){
  //do something
}

if(data instanceof JSX.Element){
  //do something 
}
```

If `instanceof` doesn't work, you may just need to do `React.isValidElement(data)`

Comment: Yup, nifty solution :)
** for the second one while comparing with JSX.Element  shows `Cannot use namespace JSX as a value` but `React.isValidElement(data)` done the job.
-Thanks  @dave